# Selenium returns a page source in which all tags names have "a0:" prefixed to them

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I use the following code to download a webpage:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.SOMEWEBSITE.com')
html = driver.page_source
```

But sometime it get things like `<a0:td>some text</a0:td>` which means it is adding `a0:` to the normal tag names. Although I can do `html.replace('a0:', '')`, I still want to find a way to get the source without these extra `a0:`.

I have tried two ways, but neither are working.

Method 1:

```
import sys
reload(sys); # change the system default encoding = utf-8
eval('sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")')
```

Method 2:

```
html = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')
```

This is the link I am crawling, it may expire in next couple of hours:

http://www.flightstats.com/go/FlightStatus/flightStatusByAirport.do?airportCode=LAX&airportQueryType=0

Comment: could you provide an example `repr(html)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you've encountered is not an encoding problem. At the start of the dumped source you see:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<a0:html xmlns:a0="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" [...]
```

The `xmlns:a0="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` bit declares a namespace named `a0`. For whatever reason, the return value from `driver.page_source`, when used with Firefox, uses XML namespaces. This behavior is not consistent across browsers, as alecxe mentioned.

Note that this is not the only problem with `driver.page_source`. A method to get the page source which I find behaves more consistently across browsers is to ask the browser to serialize its DOM tree:

```
print driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML;").encode("utf-8")
```

This does not require you to switch away from Firefox.

Comment: `outerHTML` - exactly, should have thought of that :) Good point!

Comment: Very appreciated! This is the best solution!

Answer (score 1):

This is not really about encoding. The behavior is browser-specific.

As a workaround, switch to [`ChromeDriver`](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver) (`PhantomJS` works for me also):

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = "http://www.flightstats.com/go/FlightStatus/flightStatusByAirport.do?airportCode=LAX&airportQueryType=0"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # or webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get(url)
print driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

Prints:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>
            (LAX) Los Angeles International Airport Departures
        </title>
...
```

See, no `a0` namespace prefix before the tag names.